# Test difference in proportions between values of same polytomous variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, business-intelligence

What is the right test to compare sample proportions between two values of the same polytomous variable?  Basically I'm searching for the right search term.

E.g. consider a survey question, **Q1**. What is your favorite season?  Select exactly one of the following:
a) Winter
b) Spring
c) Summer
d) Fall

Further, let's say that in a sample of 100 people the following results were obtained:

```
Q1      |  n  |  p
--------|-----|-----
winter  |  10 |  10%
spring  |  20 |  20%
summer  |  30 |  30%
fall    |  40 |  40%
```

Is the 40% for `fall` "significantly higher" than the 30% for `summer`?

Here we're not comparing proportions from different samples, it's comparing proportions for the same variable from the same sample, with the structural constraint that a respondent can choose one or neither but not both.

I imagine it would be testing the null hypothesis that the log odds ratio, e.g. `log( (0.3 / (1 - 0.3)) /  (0.4 / (1- 0.4)))` is 1.0, but I don't know which the test statistic to use.

The goal here is a simple test of "are these two significantly different at p<0.05?" for a basic business slide (all the usual caveats would still apply, that `0.05` is arbitrary, significance testing in exploratory analysis is trolling for false positives,  one should correct for multiple comparisons, small samples skew approximations, Bayesian priors exist, etc. )

Comment: If it is for a business slide, just do a test of proportions. Since you care only about the two categories, you can collapse the responses into 3 categories: fall, summer, and neither.  Analyzing the entire multinational response leads to degenerate covariance matrices, so we analyze all but the last category, meaning you're fine to look at a test of proportions between summer and fall.  There is a more robust way to do this, but it would require a null hypothesis on the proportion answering fall/summer and this is for a business slide, so I'm ok being slightly sloppy statistically.